# Openlayers - how can i show scale values on zoom control

Tags: openlayers-2

I remember seeing once zoom control in OL that had the zoom values on the scale control.

I'm looking for such solution now to let the user quick pick desired scale.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

You could add the scale Control

```
var scale = new OpenLayers.Control.Scale();

map.addControl(scale);
```

And then move the position of the scale control using CSS

```
.olControlScale{
    top: 5em !important;
    left: 0em !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you , 
I meant showing the size of each zoom as if the user want to quickly move to specific zoom like 1:5000 he knows exactly on which zoom level to click.